# pip library not getting install using windows command prompt

Tags: python, face-recognition

Command: pip Install face_recognition

```
Error code: 
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 324, in 
run
requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
   File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
 File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 821, in unpack_url
hashes=hashes
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 659, in unpack_http_url
hashes)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 882, in _download_http_url
_download_url(resp, link, content_file, hashes)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 603, in _download_url
hashes.check_against_chunks(downloaded_chunks)
   File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\hashes.py", line 46, in check_against_chunks
for chunk in chunks:
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 571, in written_chunks
for chunk in chunks:
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\ui.py", line 139, in iter
for x in it:
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 560, in resp_read
decode_content=False):
   File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 357, in stream
data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 314, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
   File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 63, in read
self._close()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 50, in _close
    self.__callback(self.__buf.getvalue())
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\controller.py", line 275, in cache_response
    self.serializer.dumps(request, response, body=body),
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\serialize.py", line 87, in dumps
).encode("utf8"),
MemoryError
```

I am getting the above error when trying to install face recognition library using command prompt. Please help.

i used windows 10

Comment: Is https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/18 helpful at all? The person there ran into the same problem initially as you did.

Comment: They also cant find answer.they try several ways but cant solve this error.